# Android Gradle plugin 7.0.0 and NDK: UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, gradle, cmake, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I recently updated Android Gradle Plugin to version 7.0.0 (Gradle version 7.0.2).
Since I did this update, my native library continues to be compiled regularly, but no .so files are generated in my final apk.

In fact, running the app the exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/it.Ettore.raspcontroller-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/it.Ettore.raspcontroller-2/lib/x86, /data/app/it.Ettore.raspcontroller-2/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libf-native-lib.so"
```

By downgrading to Android Gradle Plugin version 4.2.2 (Gradle version 6.7.1), everything works fine.

Could it be an Android Gradle Plugin bug or is it my mistake?

**build.gradle** :

```
android {

    defaultConfig {

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cFlags "-fvisibility=hidden"
                cppFlags "-fvisibility=hidden"
            }
        }

        ndk {
            moduleName "f-native-lib"
        }
        sourceSets.main {
            jni.srcDirs = ['src/main/c']
        }
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            ndk {
                debugSymbolLevel 'SYMBOL_TABLE'
            }
        }
    }


    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}
```

**CMakeList.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library(    # Sets the name of the library.
                f-native-lib

                # Sets the library as a shared library.
                SHARED

                # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
                src/main/c/mydir/myfile.c
                )


find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that you want CMake to locate.
              log
              )

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
            z-lib

            # Specifies the name of the NDK library that you want CMake to locate.
            z
            )

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
       f-native-lib

       # Links the target library to the log library included in the NDK.
       ${log-lib}
       ${z-lib}
       )
```

**Activity:**

```
static {
        System.loadLibrary("f-native-lib");
    }
```

Comment: Have tried explicitly listing the ABIs you want to build for using [`abiFilters`](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/4.2/com/android/build/api/dsl/Ndk#abiFilters:kotlin.collections.MutableSet)?

Comment: Yes @Michael, i tried to add `abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'` but unfortunately the problem persists.

Comment: Same issue here. Everything works fine with Gradle 4.2.2 but after upgrading to 7.0.0 I get the same error.

Comment: Same here. Downgrading Gradle solves the problem. Thanks, @Rene for the tip.

Comment: Hello! Do you have any updates on this problem? It seems that Gradle Plugin 7 builds only 32-bit versions of my native library. No issues are observed with Gradle Plugins 4.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue, gradle plugin version 7.0.2 fixed this

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29822387)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using tasks.whenTaskAdded in your gradle files? There is an issue with gradle plugin 7.0.0. Refer [this](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2021/09/android-studio-arctic-fox-202031-patch.html). Use 7.0.2  or greater for the resolution.

Comment: Yes, in fact I'm using tasks.whenTaskAdded

Comment: So that was the reason for this bug as mentioned in 7.0.2 patch release notes (link given above).